distributing python scripts that depend on custom packages
What is currently the correct way to distribute python scripts that depend on custom packages, so that these scripts are available system-wide?
Ideally, I want the installation to be as smooth as pip install mypackage as admin, with scripts made available through pyproject.toml ([project.scripts] if using setuptools) and custom packages automatically installed through dependencies.
However, at least with recent linux systems, python packages should now be installed within a virtual environment, so how do you reconcile that with an easy installation of python scripts?

Maybe the following is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78933843

I use them already. But if I distribute a script, the users will have to do the setup or is there some pythonic way to make it automatic?.
